# What / Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I am used by both Gamers and non-gamers alike every day.

I am on TV in different forms every night

I died but am soon to be resurrected

I am never dirty

What am I?

Hint:

> I am a well known Game Character

Big Hint

> I am used to clean

Comment: Can somebody tell me why this has been downvoted, please? Rather not make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: Well, James, you should not worry about imaginary points and votes. People vote for whatever the hell reasons they want to. Instead, stick around, and see for yourself what are the popular, highly acclaimed questions. Hint: you are not going to understand *why* they are highly acclaimed either.

Comment: I didn't DV, but since you asked :) Puzzling gets a lot of riddles, and many look like lists of facts, don't have any "twist", and/or no attempt at rhyming (not strictly required, but shows effort). Plus this sounds like trivia based on your first hint - and hints shouldn't be added immediately, let people give it a try first (puzzles should be solvable without hints!). [This meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/recent-influx-of-low-effort-riddles) is a good place to read about the community's feelings about it.

Comment: Of course, you can always edit your riddle as long as it doesn't change the puzzle. Also, it's quite common for puzzles to get upvotes once the solution is found. (Personally, I tend to hold off on voting until then, because sometimes it can seem unclear or too broad until that "eureka" moment.)  Also also - there's always chat, and it looks like [the riddle sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox) is still being visited if you want to quality check your next one before posting.

Comment: If i can give an advice for getting upvotes and/or making puzzles in general, I would say to choose your words carefully and stay bias. Saying things like "well known game characters", odds are every hardcore gamer will get angry and downvote you if the they never heard of that character even though you said he was well known. On that note, I am a hardcore gamer and never heard of any characters mentioned in answers until now except the fluffy pink one. And it would irritate me if they were the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> "soap" (the bar, and the COD character John "Soap" MacTavish)

I am used by both Gamers and non-gamers alike every day.

> gamers play COD, and everyone uses (or should be using) soap to clean themselves

I am on TV in different forms every night

> people use TVs to play COD on console, and there are often commercials for different soaps

I died but am soon to be resurrected

> John "Soap" MacTavish died in COD: Modern Warfare 3, and will return in COD: Ghosts

I am never dirty

> usually something that cleans (like soap or shampoo) is not considered dirty

Comment: TV serials are also called daily soaps, it can be reference to "I am on TV in different forms every night"

Comment: Correct! And so is @smriti for the Daily soaps

Answer (score 1):

Are you (the pretty obscure) -

> Sheen Genus (シン・ジーナス?) - Also known as the "Rising Tiger" from the videogame 'Aggressors of Dark Kombat'?  (Mr Sheen is a cleaning product and sheen is a word that you might use to describe the glare on a TV screen)

Comment: That's a good answer but not what I had in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Could you be ...

> Kirby?

I am used by both Gamers and non-gamers alike every day.

> Lots of people own Kirby vacuums, so they're used every day, by both gamers and non-gamers alike.

I am on TV in different forms every night

> There are commercials for Kirby vacuum cleaners.
>  The video game character has an anime, Kirby: Right Back at Ya!
>  Finally, the Disney show The Suite Life on Deck has a character named Kirby.
>  I'd guess one or more of these airs somewhere on TV every night...

I died but am soon to be resurrected

> The Suite Life on Deck character Kirby's actor recently died.
>  The Kirby video game franchise will launch a new title soon.

I am never dirty

> You're a vacuum cleaner. Or a shiny pink game character that never seems to be dirty.

Hint:

> I am a well known Game Character
>  ... Kirby is that, certainly.

Big Hint:

> I am used to clean
>  ... Kirby vacuum cleaners are, certainly.

The clues feel a little iffy, but the hints seem to point squarely in this direction, so giving it a shot here.